# Overriding or overloading?

Tags: java

Guys I know this question is silly but just to make sure:
Having in my class method:

```
boolean equals(Document d)
{
//do something
}
```

I'm overloading this method nor overriding right? I know that this or similiar question will be on upcoming egzam and would be stupid to not get points for such a simple mistake;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not even overloading, since the other method is called `equals`. But if you add that `s`, you will be overloading `equals`. Although, to be precise, we talk about overloading if two (or more) methods with the same name but different signature are defined *in the same class*. In your case, it is trickier, since your `equals` with its different signature partly *hides* the original `equals`. Which is usually a bad thing, because this almost always leads to hard to understand behaviour, thus subtle bugs. Whenever someone calls `equals` on an instance of your class, depending on the parameter type the call may go to a different implementation of the method.

```
class Document {
  public boolean equals(Document d)
  {
    //do something
  }
}

Document doc1 = new Document();
Document doc2 = new Document();
String string = new String();

doc1.equals(doc2); // calls Document.equals
doc1.equals(string); // calls Object.equals!
```

You would be overriding `Object.equals` if you defined your method with the exact same signature as the original, i.e.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) ...
```

In this case, both of the above calls to `equals` correctly execute `Document.equals`.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the code provided, we can't tell *for sure* whether you're overloading or overriding it.

You are most likely *overloading* the `equals(Object o)` method.

```
class A {
   void method() {..}
}

class B extends A {
   // this is overriding
   void method() {..}
}
```

And

```
// this is overloading
class A {
   void method(boolean b) {..}
   void method(String arg) {..}
   void method(int arg) {..}
}
```

P.S. you are using a bracket convention that is not widely accepted on the java world. In Java it is more common to place opening the curly bracket on the same.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you posted it could be either. If `equal` is defined in a superclass with the same parameter declarations then you are overriding it. If there is already a method called `equal`, but with different parameter types, you are overloading it.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, if you are using Java 5 and above and your intent is to override then it is highly recommended to use the `@Override` annotation before the method definition to indicate your intention. The wrong usage of this annotation (i.e. when you want to override and are not doing so) would flag a compile error.

As of Java 6 you can use the `@Override` annotation while defining methods that are 
declared in an interface the class in implementing.

Answer (score -1):

Overloading: same method name, same parameter list, different classes
Overriding: same method name, different parameter list, same or different classes.

```
Class A {

    bool Equals(Document d) {...} 

    bool Equals(A a) {...} // overloaded method
}

Class B extends A {
    bool Equals(Document d) {...} // overridden method

    bool Equals(B b) {...} // overloaded method
}
```

One thing to note, the return type does not matter, it's the name of the method and the parameter list that make all the difference.

Comment: @Tyanna "Overloading: same method name, same parameter list, different classes Overrideing: same mehtod name, different parameter list, same or different classes." - It's not true

Comment: So sorry. I got them backwards.